# How does making TV in the UK traditionally work, as opposed to the American-originated showrunner model?

Tags: production

I've seen a lot of references to the idea that the showrunner model is a very new concept to the UK, starting to be tried in the early 2000s and reaching popularity from its reasonably successful use on the Doctor Who revival. But what these articles fail to mention is how UK TV traditionally works — that is, programmes from before the idea of a showrunner, and programmes made nowadays to the traditional British model (as I believe the showrunner model has not entirely taken over in the industry at this stage; correct me if I'm wrong!).

From what I gather the duties of the showrunner were mostly split between the producer, who handled things like casting, commissioning stories, and to some degree deciding the broad strokes of the overall direction; and the script editor, whose job it was to bring the scripts tonally in line with each other, and at least unofficially to work with the producer to decide what to commission. Is this broadly correct or have I got some details wrong here? Is the script editor the producer's subordinate or are they equal in terms of "rank"? Are there any other important differences I've missed?

Comment: I suppose one difference I haven't explicitly mentioned might be that a producer would traditionally not be a writer, so has to rely on the script editor to make specific changes to scripts, or re-commission the original writers to revise their own scripts. A showrunner would usually be a writer as well I believe?

Comment: It may help to define what exactly a "showrunner" is, and what sort of TV you're talking about. A soap opera is produced very differently to a sci-fi anthology, a documentary series, or a comedy show.